# How to copy contents of similarly structured objects from one to another?

Tags: ruby

There are two different classes. But they are similarly structured, if you were to represent an instance of each class in json it would be the exact same (of course they'd have to have same values too). The first object, I don't generate because I'm writing a plugin for some application. I get the first object and I want to stick it in another class/object. How can I copy one object to the other without doing this for every field:

> new_object.field = other_object.field

**Other more specific details:**
The application I'm writing a plugin for is Logstash and the first original object is of their Logstash::Event class and the class/object I'm trying to get it into are protobuf generated classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation for `LogStash::Event`, you'll see the methods:

- [`LogStash.from_json`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/logstash-event/1.2.02/LogStash%2FEvent%2FClassMethods:from_json)
- [`LogStash#to_json`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/logstash-event/1.2.02/LogStash%2FEvent:to_json)

The source code for these method shows the basic principle for what you are trying to achieve:

```
def from_json(json)
  return self.new(JSON.parse(json))
end

def to_json(*args)
  return @data.to_json(*args) 
end
```

In other words, your implementation for converting between two "similar" objects could be something like:

```
MyProtobufClass.from_json(logstash_event.to_json)

# And vice-versa:

LogStash::Event.from_json(my_protobuff_object.to_json)
```

Such a conversion between to classes wouldn't necessarily need to be done with JSON; it could be XML or YAML or any other arbitrary data format. But JSON is already supported by the library, so seems to be the obvious choice.